# Attach a Pikaday Datepicker library to a text field on demand and show it all in 1 click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, pikaday

I am working on a Project management application that has a page for editing "Tasks" records.  THis page can how anywhere from 0 to unlimited Task records for editing.

Each Task records HTML is generated and injected into the page DOM using a JAvaScript function.  At the end of this JS function it currently runs some code like this below to attach a Date Picker library to each and every Task Due Date text input field!

Imagine a page with 100 Tasks!  100 Date Pickers being initiated on page load...not so great I would imagine!

```
var $datepicker = $(task).find(".date_due").pikaday({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',   
});
```

The library I am using is very well coded and called Pikaday - https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

So to attempt loading this on demand as needed per date filed I have used this code below instead...

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".date_due", function() {
  var $datepicker = $( this ).pikaday({
       format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'    
   });
   $datepicker.show();
});
```

This almost works as I need it.  It does load on demand now however when a user clicks a text input I need to load it and show hte Date picker all with 1 click!

This requires 1 click to load and another to open it!

You can see I attempted to trigger an open by calling the library function `$datepicker.show();` but it does not seem to be working.

The docs on https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday say...

```
picker.show()
Make the picker visible.
```

In this JSFiddle you can see that it is not making it visible as it still requires 2 clicks to view a a Date pick.  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/uuu96ckL/14/

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

There's something going on with your plugin-style wrapper which I am admittedly too lazy to look into right now, but this works:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".date_due:not(.pikaday)", function() {
  var pikaday = new Pikaday({
       field: this,
       theme: 'dark-theme',
       format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
       defaultDate: '2015-01-01'       
   });

   $(this).data('pikaday', pikaday).addClass('pikaday');

   pikaday.show();
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuu96ckL/16/).